# Angular v6, NodeJs v8.11.4 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve fs, http, https os, net, vm, timers, child_process

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, compiler-errors, node-modules

I am developing a Spring Boot + Angular 6 web application, but I am getting this errors when building the frontend code with `ng build`. 
Does anyone know how to fix?

You can find the compilation errors below. 
It seems that previously this error could have been fixed with some configuration in the webpack.

```
Date: 2018-08-26T12:06:52.322Z
Hash: 95b8c40c01fd2ba0a506
Time: 13116ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 104 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 226 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 138 kB  [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 147 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/tmp/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/rimraf'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/opera.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/edge.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/ie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/extension.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/profile.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/tmp/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/xml2js/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/profile.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '/home/myProject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
```

This is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "grpcc": "^1.1.3",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~10.5.6",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }

}
```

Comment: For obscure errors like this sometimes I try to delete your node_modules directory, run an npm -install and then try this again and things magically start working again.

Comment: So your code works when you run `ng serve` ?

Comment: @JeffryHouser I tried it many times. @Krishanu It does not work with ``ng serve``

Comment: please what was your solution to this?